# Spell check of comments in C++ code with emacs

Tags: c++, emacs, spell-checking

Is there a way to make a spell check of comments in C++ codes using emacs?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The lisp-snippet below in .emacs got it to work for me on Ubuntu Linux

```lisp
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'flyspell-prog-mode)
```

There exist alternative setups. But I think you can find them by googling flyspell-prog-mode.

Answer (score 9):

To spell check comments already in the file:

```
M-x ispell-comments-and-strings
```

To spell check comments as you type:

```
M-x flyspell-prog-mode
```

and the `.emacs` hooks kindahero suggested.

Answer (score 4):

as mirk said `flyspell-prog-mode` is the obvious way.

To share my config,

```lisp
;;; for prog modes turn on flyspell-prog-mode (checks spell only in comments)
(dolist (hook '(lisp-mode-hook
                emacs-lisp-mode-hook
                ruby-mode-hook
                yaml-mode
                python-mode-hook
                shell-mode-hook
                php-mode-hook
                css-mode-hook
                nxml-mode-hook
                crontab-mode-hook
                perl-mode-hook
                javascript-mode-hook
                LaTeX-mode-hook))
  (add-hook hook 'flyspell-prog-mode))
```

Remove those modes you don't use/want.

Answer (score 1):

Edit -> Spelling -> Ispell -> Spell-Check Comments

Comment: I am unable to find this menu item. Is this emacs 24.0?

Comment: You have possibly to install the ispell package. I use 23.3.50.1.